# Raspberry pi motion detection using raspi camera

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I have installed motion, in pi3. connected pi camera. configured motion.conf according to my needs(pi/motion/)and started motion. still i am not able to see the pics created. any additional steps needed to configure this. steps in detail.

- 1.Connected raspi cam
  2.Installed motion.
  3.raspistill command worked.
  4.edited motion.conf

started motion "sudo service motion start"
Later,Found that we need to create /dev/video0, so executed

- sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

Added below to etc/modules 
/#camera with

- v4l2 driver bcm2835-v4l2

After this also its not working any idea, where/what to check next?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure motion is using motion.conf. It's something very stupid but I remember struggling with it because if you don't tell the program to look at `/etc/motion/motion.conf` it will try to find `motion.conf` in your current folder.

So you may want to specify the conf location with :

> motion -c /path/to/motion.conf